# Transformer windings - Polarity - FEMM

Tags: transformer, polarity

I am designing a transformer in FEMM and I was wondering about the polarity of the windings. The following figures illustrate two cases.

[image]

[image]

When I run the simulation, the magnetic field in the first one is significantly bigger than in the second case so I guess the first one is the right.

Am I wrong? What parameter defines the polarity of the windings.

EDIT: There is a small mistake in the pictures. The 24 AWG / 1000 turns is the primary winding. There is a mistake with the name.

Comment: Where is the primary winding? And no, neither the secondary nor primary winding direction affects the magnetic field in the core. Try beginning the simulation when Vp is at its peak value.

Comment: @Andyaka. Thanks for noticing. I edited the question. he 24 AWG / 1000 turns is the primary winding. There is a mistake with the name.